# $\mathcal{L} \leq \mathcal{X}$, $\dim \mathcal{L} < \infty$, and $\mathcal{M}\leq \mathcal{X}$, then $\mathcal{L} + \mathcal{M}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Taken from Conways A Course In Functional Analysis Chapter 5 section 2 problem 1.

Problem Statement: In relation to Claim 2.4, show that if $\mathcal{L} \leq \mathcal{X}$, $\dim \mathcal{L} < \infty$, and $\mathcal{M}\leq \mathcal{X}$, then $\mathcal{L} + \mathcal{M}$ is closed.

I wanted to see if the solution I had below was correct.

For some $x \in \mathcal{X}\backslash \mathcal{M}$: $\mathcal{L} = \{\alpha x: \alpha \in \mathbb{F}\}$. Since $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{X}$, it follows that $\mathcal{L}+ \mathcal{M}$ is also a finite dimensional subspace (with dimension $\dim \mathcal{M}+1$) of $\mathcal{X}$. Thus, it is closed.

Comment: I may be totally wrong here, but shouldn't it be $\dim \mathcal{L} < \infty$, instead of $\dim \mathcal{X} < \infty$?

Comment: Also, in your solution, you might want to change "Since $\mathcal{X}$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{X}$" to "Since $\mathcal{L}$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{X}$. After that, I'll delete these comments.

Comment: It is not given that $M$ is finite dimensional so your proof fails.

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn't work, primarily for the reason Kavi Rama Murthy points out in the comments: you can't assume $\mathcal{M}$ is finite-dimensional. I also note that you assume or conclude that $\mathcal{L}$ is one-dimensional, which is not OK to conclude, but fine to assume if you set up an induction argument.

Let's suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{X}$, and $\mathcal{L} = \operatorname{span}(v) \le \mathcal{X}$. We aim to show $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}$ is closed. If $v \in \mathcal{M}$, then $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{M}$, which is closed, and hence we are done. Thus, assume without loss of generality that $v \notin \mathcal{M}$.

Suppose $y_n \in \mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}$ converges to $y \in \mathcal{X}$. Then $y_n = x_n + \alpha_n v$ for some $x_n \in \mathcal{M}$ and some scalar $\alpha_n$. If $\alpha_n$ were unbounded, then by taking subsequences as necessary, we could assume $\alpha_n \to \infty$ or $\alpha_n \to -\infty$, and indeed $\alpha_n \neq 0$. Then,
$$\left\|v + \frac{x_n}{\alpha_n}\right\| = \frac{\|y_n\|}{|\alpha_n|} \to 0,$$
as $y_n$ is convergent and hence bounded. On the other hand, $-x_n / \alpha_n \in \mathcal{M}$, which implies $v \in \overline{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}$, against assumption.

Therefore, $\alpha_n$ is bounded, and by taking subsequences as necessary, we may assume it is convergent. Let $\alpha$ be its limit. Then,
$$x_n = y_n - \alpha_n v \to y - \alpha v \in \mathcal{M},$$
since $\mathcal{M}$ is closed. As such, we may express:
$$y = \underbrace{y - \alpha v}_{\in \mathcal{M}} + \underbrace{\alpha v}_{\in \mathcal{L}} \in \mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}.$$

This provides the necessary tool for using induction. Recall that, if $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1} \in \mathcal{X}$, then
$$\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}) = \operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n) + \operatorname{span}(v_{n+1}).$$
As such, if $\mathcal{L}$ has dimension $n + 1$, then we may express $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{L}_1 + \mathcal{L}_2$, where $\mathcal{L}_1$ has dimension $n$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ has dimension $1$. So,
$$\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L} = (\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}_1) + \mathcal{L}_2.$$
If we assume $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}_1$ is closed for any dimension $n$ $\mathcal{L}_1$, then by the result above, $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}$ is closed for any dimension $n + 1$ $\mathcal{L}$. Couple this with the observation that, if $\dim \mathcal{L} = 0$, then $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L} = \mathcal{M}$, which is closed, we have proven by induction that $\mathcal{M} + \mathcal{L}$ is closed for any finite-dimensional $\mathcal{L}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly more direct proof that $\mathbb F v+M$ is closed, provided $M$ is closed and $v\notin M$.

The hypothesis immediately implies that
$$
  d:=\text{dist}(v,M) >0,
  $$
so, if $\lambda $ is any nonzero scalar, and $m\in M$, one has that
$$
  \|\lambda v+m\| = |\lambda |   \left\|v-\left(\frac{-m}\lambda \right)\right\| \geq  |\lambda |d,
  $$
which implies that
$$
  |\lambda |\leq \frac 1d   \|\lambda v+m\|.
  $$
The grand conclusion is that the map
$$
  \lambda v+m\in \mathbb F v+M \quad \longmapsto \quad \lambda \in \mathbb F
  $$
is continuous.
So, if $\{\lambda _kv+m_k\}_k$ is a sequence in $\mathbb F v+M$, converging to some $x\in  X$, we deduce that the $\lambda _k$ converge
to some $\lambda \in \mathbb F$, and hence also that the $m_k$ converge to some $m$, which must be in $M$.  Needless to say
$$
  x=\lim_k\lambda _kv+m_k = \lambda v+m\in \mathbb F v+M.
  $$

One may then complete the argument using induction,  as in @user847970's answer.